# Ubuntu 20.04 control volume didn't work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, configuration

I'm having a very weird situation.

Last week my laptop (Lenovo G400s) stop change volume control after login. Before login, the volume control works fine, but just after put the username and password, takes so long time to open the system, and the control volume stops to work, only the mic icon appears.

I removed the PulseAudio and reinstalled it... I try to open PulseAudio but didn't open...

When I opened the audio settings, the input and output devices didn't appear...

Did anyone have a similar problem like that?

Comment: try the command `alsa restore`. That could restore sound settings for this account.

Comment: @vanadium I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.